# NSTimer equivalent for Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, nstimer

Someone please suggest an equivalent for NSTimer in Javascript, here is my requirement.

- Want to run a piece of code after a time interval.
- Control to cancel execution at any point(Like invalidate timer in NSTimer).
- Reset timer interval.

Comment: `setTimeout` and `setInterval` are both native implementations that seem to do your job. They can also both be cleared / reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript's `setInterval()`/`setTimeout()` Methods to run the piece of code.

You can invalidate using `clearTimeout()`/`clearInterval()`

You can visit the following page from W3Schools to get more info in detail: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Thanks, will look in to it.

Comment: @Kishoretheju Welcome.